# C# import value of xml in label

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I got xml (record.xml ) with 5 name attribute

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<record>
    <name>tuttionclass</name>
    <time to="18;00" from="17:00">
        <student fee="800" started_month="falgun" class="9" name="ram"/>
    </time>
    <time to="19:00" from="18:00">
        <student fee="1000" started_month="falgun" class="10" name="shyam"/>
    </time>
    <time to="20:00" from="19:00">
        <student fee="600" started_month="magh" class="8" name="hari"/>
    </time>
    <time to="18;00" from="17:00">
        <student fee="800" started_month="falgun" class="9" name="govinda"/>
    </time>
    <time to="19:00" from="18:00">
        <student fee="1000" started_month="chaitra" class="10" name="manoj"/>
    </time>
</record>
```

coding with C#

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label[] lbl = { label1, label2, label3, label4, label5 };
    string url = string.Format("..\\record.xml");
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(url);
    foreach (var npc in doc.Descendants("time"))
    {
        string a = (string)npc.Descendants("student").First().Attribute("name");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            lbl[i].Text = a;
        }
```

**Issue:** when i loaded form it gets last value in all label. looping not working.

Comment: What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: there are 5 name attribute in xml file , when i load file i got only last name attribute in all label, i want to get all 5 name attribute  in corresponding label 1 to 5 .

Comment: Can you please post the XML?

Comment: i added xml file too, whenever i load form i got last name attribute in all label. i want to print 5 name attribute in 5 label corresponding.

Answer (score 0):

Without your actual XML for me to know if this is right or not, I've had to make a "best guess". It should be close at least.

Try this:

```
foreach (var x in
    doc
        .Descendants("time")
        .Descendants("student")
        .Select((node, index) => new { node, index }))
{
    lbl[x.index].Text = x.node.Attribute("name").Value;
}
```

Comment: i added xml file too, whenever i load form i got last name attribute in all label. i want to print 5 name attribute in 5 label corresponding.

Comment: @nareshgautam - Did you try my code? It seems to be fine to me against your XML.

Answer (score 0):

i did by another process and it works perfectly, simply i added datatable **(dt)**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label[] lbl = { label1, label2, label3, label4, label5 };
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
    string url = string.Format("..\\record.xml");
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(url);
    foreach (var npc in doc.Descendants("time"))
    {
      string a = (string)npc.Descendants("student").First().Attribute("name");
      dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{a});
    }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            lbl[i].Text = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
        }
 }
```